# Add a linked table to Entity Framework generated table, on Discriminator column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code structure:

```
class Car
class Honda : Car
class Toyota : Car
```

Of course this generates a `Discriminator` column in the `Cars` table. So, we'd have records like:

**Cars** table:

```
Id   Discriminator   Color
---------------------------
 1   Honda           Yellow
 2   Honda           Red
 3   Toyota          Yellow
```

Now, what I want to do is extend the `Car` information, by adding a `Price` per make/model. But it should be a mapping table, because it is per car make, not per car 'instance' (record).

Something like:

**CarPrices** table:

```
CarType     Amount
------------------
Toyota      10000
Honda       11000
```

Basically I want a `car.Price.Amount` property, which for a `Honda`, would get me the `11,000` value.

I think I can do the following 'mapping':

```
public class CarPrice
{
    public CarPrice(Car car, int amount)
    {
        var carType = car.GetType();

        if (carType.BaseType != null && carType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
        {
            // Get rid of the EF dynamic proxy wrapper
            carType = carType.BaseType;
        }

        this.CarType = carType.Name;
        this.Amount = amount;
    }

    protected CarPrice()
    {
        // Required by EF
    }

    [Required]
    public int Amount { get; private set; }

    [Key]
    public string CarType { get; private set; }
}
```

but I don't know how I would do a `Price` property on the `Car`, which based on its `Discriminator` to map to a `CarPrice`.

```
class Car
{
  // ...

  // TODO: I only need 'get'
  public virtual CarPrice Price { get; }
}
```

I have to avoid adding a new column to the `Cars` table, so the link most definitely has to happen on the `Discriminator` column of the existing records.

How would I approach this? Maybe I can use Fluent API to map the `car.Price` property to a custom SQL query or somehow to point it to the `CarPrices` table?

I feel the solution would revolve around [Mapping Properties of an Entity Type to Multiple Tables in the Database (Entity Splitting)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special here.  Just add the discriminator as an Entity Property, and you can use it for the Foreign Key Property.

EG

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarTypeName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CarTypeName")]
        public CarType CarType { get; set; }

    }
    public class Honda: Car
    {

    }
    public class Toyota : Car
    {

    }
    public class CarType
    {
        [Key]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CarType> Prices { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Map<Honda>(c => c.Requires("CarTypeName").HasValue("Honda"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Map<Toyota>(c => c.Requires("CarTypeName").HasValue("Toyota"));
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I can't introduce CarType on Car level. It already has a type - Honda, Toyota, etc which is stored in the Discriminator column.

Comment: I don't understand why not.  Can you clarify your model and constraints?

Comment: A couple of reasons: 1) I have 1 million records which I don't want to 'upgrade' by adding a new column to the table; 2) It should not be necessary, as the `Discriminator` column already has the information I need; 3) I don't like the `Requires` part where I have to map each 'custom' discriminator to the entity. That should not be necessary.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't map the existing Discriminator column as a ForeignKey.